Better definition of the reifying memberd_t/3
Section 7 of "Indexing dif/2" discusses general reification and the following definition is given for a reified list-membership:
memberd_t(X, Es, T) :-
   l_memberd_t(Es, X, T).

l_memberd_t([], _, false).
l_memberd_t([E|Es], X, T) :-
   if_( X = E
   , T = true
   , l_memberd_t(Es, X, T) ).

It looks really a bit too complex for me to grasp. After all, the original memberd/2 did not use if_/3.  Only subsequent optimizations did. The original version is found in section 4:
memberd(X, [E|Es]) :-
   (  X = E
   ;  dif(X, E),
      memberd(X, Es)
   ).

which then gets optimized step-by-step towards a version using if_/3.
So much for what I have tried.  Is there a better way to define memberd_t/3 that does not rely on if_/3 directly and better exposes the fact that we have here two alternatives?
One clarification to what I meant to have the alternatives in an explicit manner.  It should be next-to-trivial to write memberdr_t/3 based on it.
?- memberd_t(E,"abc",true).
   E = a
;  E = b
;  E = c
;  false.
?- memberdr_t(E,"abc",true). % how to write that with a trivial change
   E = c
;  E = b
;  E = a
;  false.

This question is not about producing a lower-level implementation as many of the answers have done (by using (\=)/2, !/0, and the like).
Quite the contrary, it focuses on providing a cleaner, high-level implementation.

If you swap the order of the subgoals in the conjunction in your original memberd/2, you get the solutions in reverse order. Is this in the direction of "how to write that with a trivial change" from your riddle? In other words, do you expect two subgoals (or maybe clauses?) that can be swapped for reversing the order of solutions?

A trivial change of a similar kind. However, to "swap the order of the subgoals in the conjunction in your/my original memberd/2," does only deteriorate the termination property for goals like ?- memberd(X,[X|Xs]).. What does change the order of answers/solutions is to exchange the arguments of the disjunction. And yes, pretty much that is what I hope to see in a pure version of memberd_t/3.

Using (;)/3:
% Version described in the paper.
memberd_t(_, [], false).
memberd_t(X, [E|Es], T) :-
    call((X=E ; memberd_t(X, Es)), T).

memberdr_t(_, [], false).
memberdr_t(X, [E|Es], T) :-
    call((memberdr_t(X, Es) ; X=E), T).

The alternative for memberd/2 can be obtained by using the commutativity of (;)/2, In the same way, the alternative for memberd_t/2 can be obtained by using the commutativity of (;)/3.

"Version described in the paper": where is this version found in the paper?

No explicitly but (;)/3 is used by treememberd_t/3. I'm over-interpreting it.

This improves on memberd_t by avoiding unwanted choicepoints when there is a clearly-matching element:
memberd_t_alt2(X, Es, T) :-
    % Filter the potential matches
    include_eq(Es, X, Ps, M),
    memberd_t_alt2_(M, X, Ps, T).

memberd_t_alt2_(match(X), X, _, true).
memberd_t_alt2_(maybe, X, Es, true) :-
    member(X, Es).
memberd_t_alt2_(maybe, X, Es, false) :-
    maplist(dif(X), Es).

include_eq([], _, [], maybe).
include_eq([E|Es], X, Ps, M) :-
    (   E \= X
        % Definite exclusion
    ->  include_eq(Es, X, Ps, M)
    ;   E == X
        % Definite match, finish here
    ->  M = match(E)
        % Maybe
    ;   Ps = [E|Ps0],
        include_eq(Es, X, Ps0, M)
    ).

Results in swi-prolog:
?- memberd_t_alt2(b, [E, b], T).
T = true. % No unwanted choicepoint

?- memberd_t_alt2(X, [a, b], T).
X = a,
T = true ;
X = b,
T = true ;
T = false,
dif(X, a),
dif(X, b).

?- memberd_t_alt2(b, [b|_], true), false.
false. % Correct


It's true that there are some leftover choice points lingering around, but this was not my question...

Can use helper:
:- use_module(library(reif)).

memberd_t_alt(X, Es, T) :-
    tmember_t(=(X), Es, T).

Results in swi-prolog:
?- memberd_t_alt(E, [a, b], T).
E = a,
T = true ;
E = b,
T = true ;
false.

?- memberd_t_alt(b, [b, b], true).
true. % No unwanted choicepoint

?- memberd_t_alt(b, [b|_], true), false.
false. % Correct


How does this now explain anything?

This version inlines (=)/3:
memberd_t(_, _, [], false).
memberd_t(D, X, Es0, T) :-
    D == f, !,
    [E|Es] = Es0,
    (   X == E
    ->  T = true
    ;   X \= E
    ->  memberd_t(f, X, Es, T)
    ;   X = E,
        T = true
    ;   dif(X, E),
        memberd_t(f, X, Es, T)
    ).
memberd_t(D, X, Es0, T) :-
    D == b, !,
    [E|Es] = Es0,
    (   X \= E
    ->  memberd_t(b, X, Es, T)
    ;   X == E
    ->  T = true
    ;   dif(X, E),
        memberd_t(b, X, Es, T)
    ;   X = E,
        T = true
    ).

But it's very explicit.

And why does this better expose that we have two alternatives?

See my edit in the question

Fixed but not optimal.

These cuts remove choicepoints that might be induced by the 3rd argument. Think of freeze(Third, (Third = [a,b] ; Third = [c] ) )

Another solution with foldl/4:
memberdf_t(X, Es0, T) :-
    Es = Es0,
    foldl(m_t(X), Es, false, T).

memberdb_t(X, Es0, T) :-
    reverse(Es0, Es),
    foldl(m_t(X), Es, false, T).

m_t(X, E, true, true).
m_t(X, E, false, T) :-
    if_(X = E, T = true, T = false).


So, does it terminates for ?- memberdr_t(1, [_,1|_], true), false?

While you are right, I still do not like it. In particular because it does not directly appeal to the commutativity of (;)/3.

Concise (but inefficient if there is no match in a long list):
memberd_t_alt3(X, Es, true) :-
    member(E, Es),
    ( X == E -> ! ; X = E ).
memberd_t_alt3(X, Es, false) :-
    maplist(dif(X), Es).

Results in swi-prolog:
?- memberd_t_alt3(E, [a, b], T).
E = a,
T = true ;
E = b,
T = true ;
T = false,
dif(E, a),
dif(E, b).

?- memberd_t_alt3(b, [b, b], true).
true. % No unwanted choicepoint

?- memberd_t_alt3(b, [b|_], true), false.
false. % Correct


Such impure optimizations were not the purpose of the question. (Note the tags too) Also note the redundancy one gets for ?- memberd_t_alt3(a,[X,Y],true).

... and worse the redundancy for ?- memberd_t_alt3(a,[X,X],true).

Comparing from the perspective of the list rather than an element, to hopefully be more intuitive:
memberd5_t(X, Es, T) :-
    memberd5_t_(Es, X, T).

% Nothing matches
memberd5_t_([], _, false).
memberd5_t_([E|Es], X, T) :-
    compare_list_elem(C, E, X),
    memberd5_t_choice_(C, Es, E, X, T).

memberd5_t_choice_(true, _, X, X, true).
memberd5_t_choice_(cont, Es, E, X, T) :-
    dif(E, X),
    % Continue searching
    memberd5_t_(Es, X, T).

compare_list_elem(C, E, X) :-
    (   E == X
        % There is a definite match within the list
    ->  C = true
    ;   true
    ).

Results in swi-prolog:
?- memberd5_t(E, [a, b], T).
E = a,
T = true ;
E = b,
T = true ;
T = false,
dif(E, a),
dif(E, b).

?- memberd5_t(b, [b, b], true).
true. % No unwanted choicepoint

?- memberd5_t(b, [b|_], true), false.
false. % Correct


Did you read the paper? Your first answer is contained it it. And it is quite inefficient (but correct). As for efficiency, that might be a problem with SWI (which is also incorrect) but not with other systems.

?- memberd2_t(b,[b,b],true).   true   ;  true, unexpected.  The original version just had one solution.

?- memberd2_t(b,[b|_],true), false.   loops, unexpected.

Changed comparison perspective - is it sufficiently intuitive?

I do not see what is intuitive here. You are pre-filtering identical values, OK. But otherwise the code is much larger than the original one.

Where is the length of the code stated as a requirement in the question? I see "It looks really a bit too complex for me to grasp", and surely compare-and-loop is easier to grasp, as a very common pattern in Prolog?

No length as such, but better exposes the fact that we have here two alternatives.

Another solution like memberd_t/3:
=(X, Y, T) :-
    X == Y, !,
    T = true.
=(X, Y, T) :-
    X \= Y, !,
    T = false.
=(Y, Y, true).
=(X, Y, false) :-
    dif(X, Y).

dif(X, Y, T) :-
    X \= Y, !,
    T = true.
dif(X, Y, T) :-
    X == Y, !,
    T = false.
dif(X, Y, true) :-
    dif(X, Y).
dif(Y, Y, false).

memberdb_t(X, [], false).
memberdb_t(X, [E|Es], T) :-
    % if_(dif(X, E), memberdb_t(X, Es, T), T = true).
    (   X \= E
    ->  memberdb_t(X, Es, T)
    ;   X == E
    ->  T = true
    ;   dif(X, E),
        memberdb_t(X, Es, T)
    ;   X = E,
        T = true
    ).

memberdf_t(X, [], false).
memberdf_t(X, [E|Es], T) :-
    % if_(X = E, T = true, memberdf_t(X, Es, T)).
    (   X == E
    ->  T = true
    ;   X \= E
    ->  memberdf_t(X, Es, T)
    ;   X = E,
        T = true
    ;   dif(X, E),
        memberdf_t(X, Es, T)
    ).


Why are you redefining (=)/3?

No need but for dif/3, it must be this implementation (just being explicit).

The question states "that does not rely on if_/3 directly". Some of those comparisons are redundant, e.g. =(Y, Y, true). is subsumed by the earlier X == Y comparison. See e.g. https://github.com/meditans/reif/blob/master/prolog/reif.pl#L170

It should be this line.
